# Dyanamic list in .net

Tags: .net

How can we create a List of dyanamic type in .Net
ex:

```
var tableType = Type.GetType("class", true);
List<tableType> Service =new   List<tableType>();
```

Comment: This isn't exactly possible. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have edited above code. I wand to initialize a list fro a dyanamic type

Comment: Still not enough information. How will you use this list? How do you want to get items in and out of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can use reflection:

```
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(tableType);
object list = Activator.CreateInstance(listType);
```

... but you won't find it terribly easy to use. Please give us more information about what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Actually, if you used `dynamic` instead of `object`, he would probably be able to use it just fine. It's not very idiomatic, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, at least not without reflection gymnastics. I recommend you use a `List<object>` or an `ArrayList` instead.